# Azure Active Sync, Will I be passwording out my users?

Tags: azure, active-directory, office365, azure-active-directory

I believe I am ready to begin a hybrid setup of Active Directory using AzureAD.

We have AD on premise with users not yet required to use complex passwords. (this is in the pipe for the next two weeks).

We have Exchange Online with users using complex passwords.

If I walk through the Azure AD sync process. The Azure server will utilize the on premise passwords for the Azure setup.

My understanding is that using Federated identity Exchange online will begin using my users' Azure AD/On Premise credentials for single sign on and meaning I will be greeted by help tickets for users unable to load their emails in outlook using their old Exchange Online credentials?

I just want to make sure I am reading everything correctly and prepared properly.

Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

No, passwords will be overridden by the ones from your AD, as far as I'm aware

Comment: So my Exchange users will need to adjust their credentials accordingly? And the local passwords will treated as the masters with only the Exchange Online changing.

Comment: https://www.puryear-it.com/configure-ad-dirsync-existing-office-365-implementation
I believe yes.